# how to return the two largest number from each array of an array in JavaScript without using for loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
    function theHighest(data) {
        let twoLargest = data.map((x) => {
            return x.reduce((prev, curr) => {
                return curr
            })
        })
        return twoLargest //returns [3,5,8]
    
    }
    console.log(theHighest([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]))
```

The above function can return the largest numbers in each array and if it could return prev along with curr in the same array the job would be done and the desired result would be achieved which is [2,3,4,5,7,8]
How can I return this without using for loops at all?

If I use for loops here is how I do it:

```js
    function theHighest(data) {
        let highestValues = []
    
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let first = 0
            let second = 0
             
            for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                    if (first < data[i][j]) {                  
                        second = first;
                        first = data[i][j];
                    }
                    else if (second < data[i][j]) {                   
                        second = data[i][j];
                    }
    
            }
            highestValues.push(first, second)
        }    
    return highestValues
        }
    console.log(theHighest([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]))
```

Thank you!

Comment: The first function does not return the largest number of each array, it returns the last number (which is different in general unless the arrays are already sorted).

Comment: Either way, that `prev` in your `reduce` function is the output of the previous iteration. You can set it to an array of the largest two numbers so far.

Comment: If the arrays are indeed already sorted, you can `map` a `slice` that takes the last two entries.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a copy, sort the array and return the two max values.

```js
function theHighest(data) {
    return [].concat(...data.map(a => a.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(-2)));
}

console.log(theHighest([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]));
```

Comment: or just `[...a].sort()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort the array as well if it not sorted

```js
function theHighest(data) {
        let twoLargest = data.map((x) => {
            // Get two largest integers
            return x.sort().slice(-2);
        })
        // Flatten the array
        return Array.prototype.concat(...twoLargest);
    
    }
   
    console.log(theHighest([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]))
```

Comment: @Thilo ah ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reduce` and `sort`

```
var output = arr.reduce( (a, c) => a.concat(c.sort().slice(-2)), [] );
```

> outputs [2,3,4,5,7,8]

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]];

var output = arr.reduce( (a, c) => a.concat(c.sort().slice(-2)), [] );

console.log( output );
```

Comment: I'm sure I have seen this approach before. Sure you don't want to look around and mark it as dupe if this is the ideal solution?

Comment: @Thilo That is exactly what my answer does.. It returns [3.5.8] which is the largest of each array

Comment: @Rajesh Sure looking for one... If I find exact duplicate I will delete this one

Comment: @Thilo Thanks for pointing out, didn't spotted it first time... it was there in the title itself.